# C# soap call on iis7.5 gives The XML-document (1, 542) contains an error

Tags: c#, mysql, xml, iis-7.5, nusoap

I've got an nusoap based wsdl on Linux which I'm trying to convert to a windows host.
The host is freshly installed, so any misconfiguration can apply for the issue.

The Host is running IIS7.5
PHP 5.5.3.8
MySQL 5.0.11

The soap request gets the right data out of the mysql database, but the application gives an error message: The XML-document (1, 542) contains an error.

And also The given type is not recognized: name=Data, namespace=http://www.my-domain.com/soap/GetData, at 
I'm trying to get the raw result out of IIS but can't get it to work.

I've tried many suggestions found by google-ing, but none works.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up making a new rest API and used that instead of the Linux solution used before.